# How "not to change" file attributes when editing via ruby?

Tags: ruby

I use `ruby -pi~ -e \"gsub(/\\\"/, \\\"'\\\")\" \"#{dir}\\*.csv\"` to replace double quotes by single quote in all files in a directory `#{dir}`

It works well but it changes the date/time of the file to current one.

**How can I preserve the time/date properties of the file(s)?**

- ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20) [i386-mingw32]
- Windows7

Comment: From mingw32, it looks like you are using Windows, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can't but you can set the modification time back to before the change like this

```
original_time= File.mtime('myfile')
p original_time

date = Time.now - 86400
File.utime(date, date, 'myfile')
p File.mtime('myfile')

File.utime(original_time, original_time, 'myfile')
p File.mtime('myfile')

#2012-10-04 02:28:25 +0200
#2012-10-03 02:28:25 +0200
#2012-10-04 02:28:25 +0200
```

utime(atime, mtime, file_name,...) → integer click to toggle source
Sets the access and modification times of each named file to the first two arguments. Returns the number of file names in the argument list.